# error when using Requestmapping at class level

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I am trying to write a basic Spring Rest hello world example using Spring 4.

I am getting 404 error when trying to use `@RequestMapping` with `@RestController` at the class level. When I remove the `@RequestMapping(value="/rest")` value above it is working with GET request on URL `http://localhost:8080/helloWorld/users/1`. But when I uncomment it I get 404 when used with the URL  `http://localhost:8080/helloWorld/rest/users/1`.

This is my controller class:

```
@RestController   
@RequestMapping(value="/rest")  
public class UserRestController {  

    @Autowired  
    private UserRepository userRepository;  

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method=RequestMethod.POST) 
    public void save(@RequestBody User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<User> list() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/users/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public User get(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        return userRepository.find(Id);
    }

    // .......

}
```

This is my `web.xml` mapping

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a star in class level:

`@RequestMapping(value="/rest/*")`

Or alternatively:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/`enter code here`rest/users")  // at class level
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST) // at method level for post
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET) // at method level for get
```

Refer this link:

https://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-requestmapping-annotation-examples/